# Is it possible to programmatically get the number of times that a certain class was referenced in the solution?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reflection

Can you programmatically get the number of times that a certain class was referenced in the solution? Or simply a code for *Find all References*

Comment: By *used* do you mean instances were created?

Comment: Do you want to process the source code or the compiled assembly?

Comment: I assume you mean *referenced* and not *created* (otherwise `if (rng.Next(10) == 0) x = new Thing();` would cause issues.

Comment: I just want to create a unit test that will somehow prove that that class was never used anywhere. Is that possible?

Comment: Why through unit test? A dependency / code coverage -analyzer  seems to be the more appropriate tool to me.

Comment: You want to know coverage ...

Comment: OK this is looking like an X-Y question, so let's rewind this a bit. *Why* do you want to do this?

Comment: @Barak Yes, but you would need to use DTE and Roslyn to parse all the classes in the solution.

To be honest, this is usually done once during refactoring to ensure it is safe to remove a class and a simple 'find all' string search for parts of class name suffices (including cases of using reflection)